# How to select data in Material UI Select from API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, material-ui

I need your help with the Select of Material UI. Im mapping through data in dropdown, but when Im selecting just one of them its changing. This is my code:

```
  const [role, setRole] = useState("");

  const roles = useSelector((state) => state.user.roles);

  useEffect(() => {
   console.log(roles);
   dispatch(getRoles());
 }, []);

<FormControl>
         <InputLabel
           id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
           style={{ fontSize: 15 }}
         >
           Role
         </InputLabel>

         <Select onChange={(e) => {setRole(e.target.value)}} style={{ paddingRight: 30 }} value={role}>
           {(roles || []).map((item, i) => {
             return (
               <MenuItem key={i} value={10}>
                 {item}
               </MenuItem>
             );
           })}
         </Select>
       </FormControl>
```

**And this is the array coming from fetching roles**  `["user", "staff", "customer_support", "admin"]`[image: This is the dropdown]

Comment: What do you mean by "but when Im selecting just one of them its changing" ? Can you explain a bit more what you want to achieve ?

Comment: When im selecting user just admin its being selected, I want to select user or staff or other roles and save it in useState like I have defined {setRole(e.target.value)}}

Comment: It's because the value inside <MenuItem /> is set to 10, you need to put the role name inside to see the change being affected. <MenuItem key={i} value={item} /> should do the work here.